# convention of group id for audit

Tags: group, audit

in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` there is `log_group = root`.  I have been asks to change that to `log_group = audit` to facilitate logging.

In RHEL 7.9 there is no `audit` group defined in `/etc/group`; someone correct me if I am wrong but there is no default defined group named *audit* in linux.  As such when doing my edit to `auditd.conf` I also have to do a `groupadd audit`.  Easy enough.  But given this is a rather important thing is there any convention, or recommendation, regarding choosing the group id for such a thing?

This is for standalone servers having all user accounts locally in `/etc/passwd`

Comment: Do you all use a centralized identity management solution, or is it local accounts/groups only? You'd have the group if it doesn't exist elsewhere.

Comment: local accounts, in /etc/passwd

Comment: If that's the case, just add the group and change it in the config